# solve triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Please, help me, I don't know how solve this triple integral, I was trying with spherical coordinates but I can't
$$
\iiint e^{ax+by+cz-x^2-y^2-z^2}dV
$$
where $V$ is all $\Bbb R^3$ and $a,b,c$ are constants

Comment: You don't need to proceed a change of variables here -- apply Fubini theorem directly, and the problem will be reduced to the evaluation of the integrals $\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{ax-x^{2}}dx}$, which can be transofmed into $-e^{\frac{a^{2}}{2}} \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-t^{2}}dt}$, the last one can calculated using the polar coordinates.

Comment: thanks, other question. Which sustitution you did?

Comment: I have posted is as a separete answer due to the lack of space in the comment window.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}{e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}} dx dy} = I^{2}$$ where $$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-t^{2}} dt}$$

It's possible to evaluate $I^{2}$ using the polar coordinates transformation: $$(r, \varphi) \rightarrow (x, y)$$ by taking $$x= r\cos(\varphi), y = r \sin(\varphi))$$ $$r \geq 0, 0 \leq \varphi \leq 2 \pi$$ The Jacobian of the transformation is equal to $r$, so the integral reduces to the following form $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}{e^{-r^{2}} r dr d\varphi} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}{r e^{-r^{2}} dr d\varphi}$$ The last one can be integrated by parts.